# memset and static array declaration vs malloc

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, memset

Malloc is used for dynamic memory allocation. However, this code doesn't use malloc, but is dynamic. In what case would I use malloc? Or is this code doing something really bad?

Sometimes, I see this style of coding in answers on Leetcode.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);
    char test[len+1];
    memset(test,0,len+1);
    strcpy(test,argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n",test);
    return 0;
}
```

so why would I do this instead?

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);
    char *test = calloc(len+1,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(test,argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n",test);
    free(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no point using memset or calloc if you're immediately going to overwrite the memory with strcpy.

Comment: One reason might be that you wish the allocation to outlive main(), (maybe you are going to signal it to another thread), or perhaps your compiler does not support VLA.

Comment: @rici right, my b